# How do I return the nth to nth+10 largest value labels in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, filtering, pivot-table

There has got to be a way to do this, but I can't figure it out. It's easy to get a pivot table (and pivot chart) to display the top-10 based on subtotal values. But, I want the pivot table to display the 11th to 20th largest rows based on subtotal values. The problem is that the number of lines and columns in the pivot table are dynamic, based on ever-changing source data.

I've tried filtering the pivot table, but I can filter only for the top or bottom values, not for arbitrary `LARGE()` ranges in the middle. I've also tried to set up a field outside the pivot table that identifies the 11th-20th largest rows, but this field breaks if the number of rows or columns in the pivot table changes.

Are there any other ideas out there? Unfortunately, the PowerPivot or PowerQuery tools aren't available for me. Just vanilla Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go on but I'm guessing you have totals for rows and wish to filter these by rank. If so, maybe repeat this Sigma values entry and for this change Show Values As to Rank Largest to Smallest, then filter the column (not just the PT) containing the new row totals with Number Filters, Between..., is greater than or equal to `11`, select And, is less than or equal to `20`.